# fast text reader c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using the following code to read and combine number of texts in one string:

```
            foreach (string path in filePaths)
            {


                StreamReader singfile = new StreamReader(path);

                string  file_text = singfile.ReadToEnd();
                combinetexts += file_text + "\n";

                fs.Close();

            }
```

and as I know, the string combinetexts will copy n times as much as the number of filepaths. is it possible the to do that orcedure using string builder ? I tried but it doesn't. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: to do the same procedure using string builder to avoid the copy n times

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a short LINQ way of doing it:

```
string result = string.Join("\n", filePaths.Select(x => File.ReadAllText(x)));
```

Or with C# 4 (which has better handling of type inference wrt method group conversions):

```
string result = string.Join("\n", filePaths.Select(File.ReadAllText));
```

If you're using .NET 3.5 you'll need to create an array of the strings, as `string.Join` didn't have as many overloads then:

```
string result = string.Join("\n", filePaths.Select(x => File.ReadAllText(x))
                                           .ToArray());
```

This has the disadvantage of reading all of *all* the files before performing the concatenation, admittedly - but it's still better than the repeated concatenation in the original code. It *might* also be more efficient than using `StringBuilder` - it depends on the `string.Join` implementation.

See my [article on `StringBuilder`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for why the original code is really inefficient.

EDIT: Note that this does *not* include a trailing `\n` at the end. If you *really* want to add that, you can :)

Comment: amazing code. thank you. do i need to loop through the filepaths ?

Comment: @JoneMamni: No, LINQ does that for you. That's *all* the code you need to replace the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible, use

```
StringBuilder combinetexts = new StringBuilder();
...

combinetexts.Append(file_text);
combinetexts.Append("\n");;
```

Comment: Just for the record: StringBuilder is **not** immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your example using a StringBuilder instead of a string:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string path in filePaths) 
    sb.AppendLine(File.ReadAllText(path)); 

string result = sb.ToString();
```

(I've also taken the liberty to shorten/optimize your code a bit. [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) reads the complete contents of a file without having to open a StreamReader manually. In addition, `AppendLine` automatically adds a `\n` at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to use an StringBuilder to manipulates strings.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14936/StringBuilder-vs-String-Fast-String-Operations-wit

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
StringBuilder strBuilder= new StringBuilder();
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
     StreamReader singfile = new StreamReader(path);
     string  file_text = singfile.ReadToEnd();
     strBuilder.AppendLine(file_text);
     fs.Close();
}
Console.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use StringBuilder, there are various ways to "optimize" this code.

**TL;DR**: Skip to the last part of this post for the best way to do this.

Here's stage 1 changes to your code:

```
StringBuilder combinetexts = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path);

    string  file_text = fs.ReadToEnd();
    combinetexts.Append(file_text).Append("\n");

    fs.Close();
}
```

Secondly, before building the `StringBuilder` you can calculate how much space you actually need, this will reduce the chance of copying the string even further:

```
long totalSize = 0;
foreach (string path in filePaths)
    totalSize += new FileInfo(path).Length + 1; // +1 = \n

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Convert.ToInt32(totalSize));
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path);

    string  file_text = fs.ReadToEnd();
    combinetexts.Append(file_text).Append("\n");

    fs.Close();
}
```

Lastly I would use `using (...)` instead of the `fs.Close();` call:

```
long totalSize = 0;
foreach (string path in filePaths)
    totalSize += new FileInfo(path).Length + 1; // +1 = \n

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Convert.ToInt32(totalSize));
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string  file_text = fs.ReadToEnd();
        combinetexts.Append(file_text).Append("\n");
    }
}
```

Then I would use LINQ a bit more and switch to using `File.ReadAllText` instead of an explicit `StreamReader`, and then combine the lines of code a bit:

```
long totalSize = filePaths.Sum(path => new FileInfo(path).Length + 1);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Convert.ToInt32(totalSize));
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    combinetexts.Append(File.ReadAllText(path)).Append("\n");
}
```

However, as it turns out, there's an even better way to do this:

```
string combinetexts = String.Join("\n", filePaths.Select(path => File.ReadAllText(path)));
```

or in C# 4.0 which can better infer the right way to handle method group conversions:

```
string combinetexts = String.Join("\n", filePaths.Select(File.ReadAllText));
```

This will do *all* of the above, it will:

1. Read in all the files
2. String.Join will calculate the total size needed to hold the entire string
3. Then it will combine all the texts, with a `\n` between each